# Django KeyError when starting

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I accidentally pulled an old git repo of my Django build ( It's running on a Heroku dyno  ) and it had overwritten my entire local build, I managed to restore it back to the latest git repo which was previously working on my local build ( but not my Heroku dyno ) and the server now won't run locally or on my live build?

Error from the shell:

`python manage.py runserver`

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/johnnie/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/johnnie/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/johnnie/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/johnnie/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/johnnie/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/johnnie/myproject/myproject/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 141, in <module>
    del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
KeyError: 'OPTIONS'
```

edit:

```
del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
```

was a section added by Heroku when committed by git.
removed this plus other Heroku changes which resolved issues.

Comment: as the error said, you do not have a key named `OPTIONS` in `DATABASES` dictionary.

Comment: I managed to fix that issue but now have

  File "/home/johnnie/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

I'm wondering if these issues are caused due to the fact that Heroku has made some changes to my files and so now my local version is suffering from the changes?